# not able to click the search bar tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got a tableview containing array of names. The search bar works perfectly filtering the names in the table view.

The problem is the `didSelectRowAtIndexpath` is not getting fired when clicking the search tableview cell. Could you help me out?

What is the thing that I'm missing? Should I include any special delegate to involve search tableview cell click.

Below is the image and code.

[image]

```
  -(void)search
 {
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44)];
searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.tableViewFriendsList.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
 }
 - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
 [tableView setRowHeight:70];
 [tableView reloadData];
 }
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {       

   if (tableView == self.tableViewFriendsList) {
    NSString *friendsID =[[[self.friendsDictionary objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
    [[FacebookHelper sharedFacebookHelper] postOnWallWithDelegate:self andID:friendsID];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    NSLog(@"I ve come here");
    NSString *friendsID =[friendsListIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[FacebookHelper sharedFacebookHelper] postOnWallWithDelegate:self andID:friendsID];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set

```
searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

Answer (score -1):

I do something in one of my projects that may be of assistance:

```
// add gesture to detect when table view is being tapped so that keyboard may be dismissed
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                        action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Moreover I am wondering why you have a search bar **within** a table cell. Would you mind posting a screen shot of it in your app? I am afraid you may be doing more work than is necessary.

Comment: the problem is i m not able to fire the didselectRowAtIndexpath for searchtable.when the searchtableview cell is clicked i dont have problem dismissing the keyboard ...any idea